# StackExchange API's request data is blank in Drupal 7

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, missing-data

I'm trying to implement this simple request in Drupal 7 on my local machine:

```
$request = drupal_http_request('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow');
$json_response = drupal_json_decode($request->data);
```

> For your information:
>
> - [drupal_http_request()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) performs an HTTP request.
> - [drupal_json_decode()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_decode/7) converts an HTML-safe JSON string into its PHP equivalent.

From my side, the endpoint seems to work fine, as it sends a correct JSON result with all the users.

But I still can't recover the data because it's like `$request->data` appears like blank despite the "4468 characters". That's wierd.

[image]

While I'm supposed to get something like that, with a very beautiful JSON string:

[image]

If I try with another API, like Twitter for example, it works fine (*sorry I put an old depreciated endpoint but it's not important, I get the data back anyway*) :

[image]

Does someone have a clue about that strange issue?

Comment: [The API response is GZIPped](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression).  Use `gzinflate`, or whatever, on the response before trying to JSON decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BrockAdams said, the string is compressed and need to be uncompress depending on the `$request->headers`.

```
$request = drupal_http_request('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow');

if (isset($request->headers['content-encoding'])) {
  if ($request->headers['content-encoding'] == 'gzip') {
    $request->data = gzinflate(substr($request->data, 10));
  }
  elseif ($request->headers['content-encoding'] == 'deflate') {
    $request->data = gzinflate($request->data);
  }
}

$json_response = drupal_json_decode($request->data);
```